# I need help with my webcam

Tags: drivers, microphone, webcam, camera

So I have this issue with my webcam(It has a microphone built in) where ubuntu does not see it as a camera nor a microphone.  I ran sudo hwinfo --usb on the terminal it showed

```
06: USB 00.2: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: RUmI.54pYTQlWHW1
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2
  SysFS BusID: 1-7:1.2
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "SN0002 1080P Web Camera"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x2bdf "SN0002"
  Device: usb 0x0280 "1080P Web Camera"
  Revision: "50.02"
  Serial ID: "SN0002"
  Driver: "snd-usb-audio"
  Driver Modules: "snd_usb_audio"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v2BDFp0280d5002dcEFdsc02dp01ic01isc01ip00in02"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_usb_audio is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_usb_audio"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #11 (Hub)
```

System specifications:

```bash
OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64  
Host: B660M Pro RS/AX  Kernel: 6.2.0-32-generic  
Uptime: 54 mins  Packages: 2158 (dpkg), 20 (snap)  
Shell: zsh 5.9  
Resolution: 1920x1080  
DE: GNOME 44.0  
WM: Mutter  
WM Theme: Adwaita  
Theme: Cold Metal - No Logo [GTK2/3]  
Icons: Papirus-Dark [GTK2/3]  
Terminal: gnome-terminal  
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-12400F (12) @  
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT/  
Memory: 4471MiB / 15820MiB
```

Can you help me please, thank you

Edit: I have run cheese and it says no device found along with a black background.

Comment: "`Driver: "snd-usb-audio"`" it does detect your microphone.

Comment: I dont think so because when I go to settings > sound > input devices. It says "no input devices next to input device.